# Securing string in APK

Tags: c#, android, security, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am developing an android app using Mono for Android by Xamarin. I am currently working on adding in-app-purchase capability using the Google Play API. To do so, I need to send Google the public license key from within my app. Regarding this issue, Google recommends the following:

> Security Recommendation: It is highly recommended that you do not
>   hard-code the exact public license key string value as provided by
>   Google Play. Instead, you can construct the whole public license key
>   string at runtime from substrings, or retrieve it from an encrypted
>   store, before passing it to the constructor. This approach makes it
>   more difficult for malicious third-parties to modify the public
>   license key string in your APK file.

I have never dealt with encryption, hacking/cracking or any of other facet of software security, so I am not sure how to implement Google's advice. My question is how does one *adequately* secure a string in an Android APK made with Mono for Android without having to be a security expert?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not to sound too bold, but I believe you can safely ignore their suggestion. The security benefits of what they're suggesting are minimal at best.

For a more detailed discussion read this: [How to protect Google Play public key when doing InApp Billing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671865/how-to-protect-google-play-public-key-when-doing-inapp-billing)

The truth is that none of the methods described there are perfectly secure. If someone is determined to figure your public key out, they will. No matter what you do, the public key will end up being passed to the ctor, so a malicious user could always examine it at this point. All the "games" they are suggesting are just making this a bit more difficult, but definitely not impossible.

I think your best bet is accepting this for what it really is. This key is **public** for a reason and you need to live with the fact that it could be compromised easily. Since everybody else sleeps well at night knowing this, I see no reason why you shouldn't as well :)

If you really can't sleep at night and want to do something.. Place your key in your code with the first two characters switched. Then during runtime, switch the two characters back before using the key. This should be enough to protect yourself against brute force automated attacks.. Intelligent attacks you can't do anything about.

**Edit:**

If you're looking for an industry standard way to protect your code, use a commercial obfuscator. These tools are designed for this purpose. Some examples are [Mono for Android, code obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352440/mono-for-android-code-obfuscation). Make sure to use fully featured commercial versions that include string encryption.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I still would like to know some good industry standard method of solving this issue, since the Google Play key is not the only key string in my app (for example the Facebook app key too, and maybe others in the future).

Comment: Use a commercial obfuscation tool. These tools go over your code and make it harder to decompile. Commercial ones usually include an automatic string encryption feature which makes sure all of your hardcoded strings (like keys) are never kept plaintext in your app and are decoded in runtime. Plenty of obfuscators are available for c# / android. They are very easy to integrate into your build process and they do all of the heavy lifting for you in the area of protecting your code.

Comment: Here's a list of some of the techniques used by commercial obfuscators to annoy potential hackers to death: http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/features.htm. Always keep in mind that a determined hacker will still be able to overcome all this.. but it will be much less fun for him ;)